# Automatically scraping data from web page that e-mails a download link using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, automation, screen-scraping

I'm trying to download data from the following website: https://mrcc.illinois.edu/cliwatch/northAmerPcpn/getArchive.jsp

My ultimate goal is to create a script that I can set up to run daily which grabs yesterday's actual precipitation data as a CSV for Canada and North America. That means I need the following options selected (in order): Actual, comma separated values, MPE, Canada & North America. Then begin date and end date set up appropriately for the previous day's date.

I successfully created the following script which navigates the selections for me (I did this by looking at the URL the form produces after the selections are made):

```
library(lubridate)

yesterday_year <- lubridate::year(Sys.Date()-1)
yesterday_month <- lubridate::month(Sys.Date()-1)
yesterday <- lubridate::day(Sys.Date()-1)

mrcc.site <- 'https://mrcc.illinois.edu/cliwatch/northAmerPcpn/getArchive2.jsp?datatype=actual&dataformat=csv&dataset=mpe&reg=northAmer&syr='
mrcc_smo_1 <- '&smo='
mrcc_dy_1 <- '&sdy='
mrcc_yr_1 <- '&eyr='
mrcc_smo_2 <- '&emo='
mrcc_dy_2 <- '&edy='
mrcc_yr_2 <- '&edy='
email <- '&email=myemail%40gmail.com'
yesterday_year <- paste(yesterday_year)
yesterday_month <- paste(yesterday_month)
yesterday <- paste(yesterday)
download.url <- paste(mrcc.site, yesterday_year, mrcc_smo_1, yesterday_month, mrcc_dy_1, yesterday, mrcc_yr_1, yesterday_year, mrcc_smo_2, yesterday_month, mrcc_dy_2, yesterday, email, sep="")

browseURL(download.url, browser = getOption("Chrome"),
          encodeIfNeeded = FALSE)
```

The final piece of code can open the link that's created.

My problem now is that the web site is set up to e-mail you a .tar.gz file download link, which is really inconvenient for me. I would just like to have a way to automatically download this file to my computer with my script instead of having to manually go into my email and click this link. Is there a way to grab the link to the download file that is generated? Maybe from the page itself rather than from my e-mail?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can't change the behavior of the website. You can import of the file from your email into R and take it from there.

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping there might be some hidden way to grab the download link that is generated by the website. The format of the link is http://mrcc.illinois.edu/cliwatch/northAmerPcpn/dataRetr/dataYYYYMMDD080522.tar.gz, with the last numbers automatically generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think you can do this and bypass the email...

Basically, when you request the file, it gives you a timestamp. That is used to generate the download link. Try it out and let me know if it works...

```
library(lubridate)
library(httr)

start_year <- lubridate::year(Sys.Date()-100)
start_month <- lubridate::month(Sys.Date()-100)
start_day <- lubridate::day(Sys.Date()-100)

end_year <- lubridate::year(Sys.Date())
end_month <- lubridate::month(Sys.Date())
end_day <- lubridate::day(Sys.Date())

mrcc.site <- 'https://mrcc.illinois.edu/cliwatch/northAmerPcpn/getArchive2.jsp'
query <- list("datatype"   = "actual",
              "dataformat" = "csv",
              "dataset"    = "mpe",
              "reg"        = "northAmer",
              "syr"        = start_year,
              "smo"        = start_month,
              "sdy"        = start_day,
              "eyr"        = end_year,
              "emo"        = end_month,
              "edy"        = end_day,
              "email"      = "a@a.com")

# request that file is generated
response <- GET(mrcc.site, query = query)

# build the download file url
response_date <- format(with_tz(response$date, tzone = "America/Chicago"),
                        "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
file_url <- paste0("http://mrcc.illinois.edu/cliwatch/northAmerPcpn/dataRetr/data",
                   response_date, ".tar.gz")

# wait some time...
file_header <- headers(HEAD(file_url))[["Content-Length"]]
if(file_header > 113 & file_header != 1126){
  # file is bigger than 113 (so it has been generated), and is not 1126 (no file exists)
  download.file(file_url, destfile="c:/tmp.tar.gz")
}
```

Comment: This worked! I didn't realize the numbers following the YYYYMMDD were the rest of a timestamp. Good thinking.